# How can I wrap a list of columns into an array in my SELECT query?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I've got a query that I'm trying to form using SQLAlchemy against a postgres DB.

Here's my query:

```
select id, array_remove(ARRAY[a.value1, b.value2, etc.], null) FROM table t
JOIN a on t.id = a.id
JOIN b on t.id = b.id
```

This provides a return where the second column is an array of values from different tables. The goal is to have those columns represented in a single column value separated by a comma.

In SQL Alchemy, I'm generating those tables on the so in doing so, I have a list of the Column object themselves. When I'm building my query, I've got the joins and whatnot down but how can I structure the code so that I pass in my list of columns and it results in the expected "ARRAY[column1, column2, etc.]" I expect to see in SQL?

Here's where I'm at so far:

```
my_query.add_columns(func.array_remove(ARRAY(id_cols), null))
```

Neither the ARRAY type or array function (literal) appear to take a list of columns. I tried using func.cast to a an array and that also didn't work as it wouldn't take a list of columns. Using a string list of column names isn't ideal because these columns might conflict in name... I guess the fully qualified name might be okay but seems to also be difficult to get with SQLAlchemy.

Comment: Are you looking for the function [`array_to_string`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-array.html)?

Comment: No, the values from my tables are integers. Array to string would be applicable if the values were arrays themselves; I'm simply trying to represent multiple columns of integer type as a single array field.

Comment: I meant `array_to_string(array_remove(ARRAY[a.value1, b.value2, etc.], null), ',')`. Or what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

you need to use the `PostgreSQL ARRAY literal` instead.

```py
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import array

my_query.add_columns(func.array_remove(array(id_cols), null))
```